# Trigger iSeries job on new message in data queue

Tags: message-queue, ibm-midrange

[IBM WebSphere MQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ/mapfiles/product_welcome_wmq.htm) has functionality called triggering that allows for an iSeries program to be called when a new message arrives on the queue. Is there a way to allow for the same functionality with a native iSeries [data queue](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaik/rzaikdq.htm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, set up a CL program that waits on the QRCVDTAQ() API and when a message comes in, call the program, submit a job, etc.  The sender would be sending messages that contain the library/program or perhaps even the entire CALL command.  You can use QCMDEXC() in the CL to run/submit the program.

Comment: It might be useful to have the listening CL program be started as an autostart job for a related subsystem.